# I can't post value from dynamic dependents dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm new to jQuery and have a problem where I am unable to post a value which originated from a dependent dynamic dropdown list.

Here is the code I have written:

**index.php**

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="branddd" onchange="change_brand()" required>
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="color:gray" required >brand</option>
                <?php       
                $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from brand");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                ?>
                <option name="brand" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row["name"];?></option>
                <?php
                }   
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="model">
            <select name="model">
                <option required>model</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript I have written to load data from MySQL into the 2nd dropdown box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_brand()
{

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest () ;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?  brand="+document.getElementById("branddd").value,false) ;
    xmlhttp.send(null) ;
    document.getElementById("model").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText ;

}
</script>
```

**ajax.php**:

```
<?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"test_db");
    $brand=$_GET["brand"];

    if($brand!="")
    {
        $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from model where brand_id=$brand");
        echo "<select>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<option>"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You say you're trying to POST but you're using GET. To POST with jquery you can use [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: you must have a name of your first select

Comment: thanks how i forgot i just add it but i get id value then name value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add name attribute in your `select[id="branddd"]`** and add `name="brand"` to `select tag` not in `options` like,

```
<select id="branddd" name="brand" ...
```

Check you div is closed after your `select[name="model"]`.And add `required` to the select box instead of its `option`

And at server end you need not to echo `<select>` again try this only,

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
   echo "<option>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}
```

And add id to `select` instead of `div`

And if you are using jquery then your onchange event can be short like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#branddd').on('change',function(){
        this.value && // if value!="" then call ajax
           $.get('ajax.php',{brand:this.value},function(response){
            $('select[name="model"]').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

In case of using jquery you must need to remove `onchange` from `<select id="branddd" onchange="change_brand()" required>` and would be just like `<select id="branddd" required>`

Comment: thanks when i tried first suggestion, i got value from 2nd dropdown on my form action, but not from 1st one

Comment: Try my updated answer and add `name` in your `brand select box`. It will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for ur effort, i just did it but it give me the brand "id" not "name", so im trying to echo brand "name" on i hidden <input> and see if i can solve it

Comment: Don't remove `id` but add `name` like `<select id="branddd" name="brand" ...` . See my updated answer.

Comment: it's what i did then in my form action i got brand "id" and model "name", and i think it's because of  <option name="brand" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row["name"];?></option> , so i get value then name

Comment: Remove `name="brand"` from `option`, as the `name` must be added to `select` not in `option`

Comment: still getting "id" value not <select>text</select>